# Changing Deque elements

Tags: java, deque

I have made my own Deque class with the following methods:

```
Deque#pushLeft(E e), pushRight(E e), popLeft() and popRight().
```

Is it possible to make a method which could change any elements of a Deque? I would like to edit them from left and from right. So `editRight(index, E newElement)` and the same for `editLeft`.

How would I start doing this? Would I need to use an Iterator?

Comment: you need to alter any element by index or just head and tail elements?

Comment: the idea of queue is that you can change it only from tail and head. If you need to update something in the middle - it is not queue

Comment: We cannot answer your question without seeing your current code.

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like a LinkedList - that has an API that allows you to add / remove / edit at each end.

Comment: The answer to the question of how to do this depends entirely on how you've implemented `Deque`. If you could show the definition of the data structure we could probably provide some guidance.

Comment: @sprinter I have added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented your `Deque` as a double linked list. The simplest way to support `editLeft` and `editRight` is to just step along the links until you reach the node you wish to change.

Something like:

```
public void editLeft(int index, Item item) {
    Node node = right;
    while (node != null && index > 0) {
        node = node.prev;
        index--;
    }
    if (node != null) {
        node.item = item;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalRangeException("Attempt to edit value with illegal index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deque is ADT and it could be implemented by linked list or Arrays as data structures. Your answer depends upon the type of data structure being used to store elements.and also I would suggest you to implement a peek operation and it would give you a reference of an element for edit propose .peek operation could be used by other high-level operations like delete/contains etc.